# Issue Accessing Environment Variables Set Using `dotenv` in Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, dotenv

In my Node.js application, I'm facing an issue with accessing environment variables set using `dotenv`. I have configured `dotenv` in my main application file (`app.js`), and I can access the environment variables there. However, when I attempt to access the same variables in another module (e.g., `userController.js`), they appear as `undefined`. Surprisingly, in my `connect.js` file, it works fine. This behavior has left me confused.

Here's my project setup:

**app.js**:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import express from "express";
import { URL, fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { connectDB } from "./db/connect.js";
// ... other imports and code ...
```

**userController.js**:

```js
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { User } from "../models/userModel.js";

console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET); // This prints "undefined"
```

**connect.js**:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

async function connectDB() {  // Environment variables work fine inside this function
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
        family: 4,
        dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
    });
}

export { connectDB };
```

**Folder Structure**

```
|-- .env  
|-- .gitignore  
|-- README.md  
|-- app.js  
|-- controllers  
|   `-- userController.js  
|-- db
|   `-- connect.js
|-- middleware  
|-- models  
|-- node_modules  
|-- package-lock.json  
|-- package.json  
|-- public  
|-- routes  
|-- views
```

**.env** File

```
JWT_SECRET="thisissomerandomsecret"  
DB_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017"  
DB_NAME="authenticationDB"
```

I've read that I should only need to configure `dotenv` once in the main application file, and it seems to work when I use the environment variables in the `connect.js` file. Do I need to import it in each file where I require environment variables? This is a personal project, so I could hardcode the values, but I'd like to understand why this might be happening.

What could be causing the environment variables to be inaccessible in other module?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried importing and configuring `dotenv` in `userController.js` and when I do that it works fine but not when I import it only in `app.js`